# Carga dinámica de archivos

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5

Buenas tardes: Estoy desarrollando un sistema con carga dinámica de módulos en una sola página con JavaScript, también utilizo PHP y Bootstrap con POO y MVC.

He tenido problemas con la carga de archivos con fragmentos de código HTML y scripts juntos; definitivamente, después de casi una semana de consultas en internet, averigüé que, simplemente, no se puede. Bueno sí se puede, con JavaScript e innerHTML, pero no toma en cuenta ningún script, lo interpreta como texto.

La carga de los scripts en cada módulo (archivo.php) se debe a que no puedo colocar en el archivo .js que se carga al principio, procesos de objetos de un módulo que no ha sido cargado todavía, eso provoca un error. Por ejemplo, si se coloca una referencia al evento submit del botón GUARDAR del módulo Nuevo Producto que no ha sido cargado todavía, arroja un error. Por esa razón coloqué en cada encabezado de los archivos de los módulos todos los scripts que corresponden a procesos propios.

Ya intenté con rutas amigables y es un tema complicado lo de las rutas, ya que debo cambiarlas en cada proceso debido a que tengo los archivos .php (con HTML y JavaScript juntos) dentro de carpetas/subcarpetas. Utilizo MVC y, por ejemplo, en el formulario del Login no utilizo PHP (action, method, etc.) para enviar los datos al Controlador, todos esos procesos los hago con JavaScript. Dentro del controlador debo llamar a otros archivos PHP y cada uno tiene sus rutas de acceso; después de validar el Login, éste se cierra y abre la plantilla del sistema, si quiero insertar dinámicamente un módulo después de seleccionarlo en el menú, hago el llamado al mismo Controlador y comienzan los errores con las rutas, ya que me dice que no puede conseguir el archivo secundario que se llama dentro del Controlador porque no consigue la ruta. Debo decir que éste método si acepta los archivos con HTML y JavaScript juntos ya que se hace por PHP utilizando include o require_once, pero se me complica con el tema de las rutas.

Estos archivos secundarios en el Controlador los utilizo para, por ejemplo, limpiar los datos recibidos para evitar inyecciones SQL, para obtener otros datos necesarios y para llamar, de forma obligatoria ya que la POO lo requiere, al Modelo.
Después de analizar los problemas se me ocurrió combinar JavaScript, PHP y GET con éste “método”, sin utilizar el archivo .htaccess:

1.- Después de validar el Login, con JavaScript llamo a la plantilla del sistema así:

```
window.location.href = '../vistas/plantillaPrincipal.php?modulo=dashboard';
```

le paso por $_GET la variable módulo con el valor “dashboard” para que al cargar la plantilla incluya en la “zona de módulos cargados” el dashboard.

2.- Al cargar la plantilla principal coloqué en la cabecera del archivo el siguiente código para que reciba las variables por $_GET:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_GET['modulo']) {
            if ($_GET['modulo'] == 'dashboard') {
                $moduloCargado = "dashboard.php";
                } else {

                require_once("../controladores/viewsController.php");

                $instanceController = new viewsController();
                $path = $ instanceController ->getPathController($_GET['modulo']);
            }
        }
    ?>
```

3.- Al momento de la carga inicial de la plantilla se carga también el módulo dashboard sin ningún problema (los 2 archivos están en el mismo nivel).

4.- Con JavaScript capturo el evento click de cada ítem del menú y llamo a una función que recibe como único parámetro el id de ese ítem (tiene como valor el nombre del módulo).

```
<a class="nav-link menu_lateral activo" id="dashboard">
      <span><i class="fas fa-home icono_menu_seleccionado"></i></span>Inicio
</a>
```

5.- Lo que hace la función es pasarle a la plantilla principal, por $_GET el nombre del módulo:

```
function selecciones_menu(moduloSeleccionado) {
    const templatePpal = document.getElementById('modulo_cargado');
    let ruta = 'plantillaPrincipal.php';

    $.get(ruta+'?modulo='+moduloSeleccionado);
}
```

6.- La plantilla principal recibe el nombre del módulo y se lo pasa al Controlador, éste lo revisa para que no venga con código malicioso y lo pasa al Modelo. En el Modelo hago una consulta a la BD para que, según el nombre del módulo, desde la tabla menú devuelva la ruta donde se encuentra ése módulo, devuelve ésa ruta al Controlador y la recibe la plantilla principal en la variable $path. En la “zona de carga de los módulos” sólo coloco un include de la variable $path.

```
<?php include $path; ?>
```

7.- El problema que se me presenta, y es el motivo de mi consulta, es que no pasa nada (apatentemente), se puede ver el dashboard en pantalla todavía y no el módulo seleccionado en el menú.
Al revisar en la etiqueta Network de la consola para revisar qué me devolvía el Controlador, conseguí que sí carga el archivo seleccionado pero por alguna razón que desconozco no lo carga en el DOM. Y no sólo eso, también me muestra no sólo el fragmento del código HTML con JavaScript, sino que también viene con la estructura de toda la plantilla que ya está cargada, pero no lo pinta en el DOM.
He investigado mucho en internet y en otros foros y grupos y no he conseguido solucionar éste problema, es decir, como realizar la carga de los archivos sin tener problemas.

Comment: El modulo de `PHP` que intentas cargar tiene su propio `HTML`, `body`, etc y tu pagina en la que intentas cargar el modulo tambien?

Comment: La plantilla base sí tiene toda la estructura HTML, pero el archivo que intento cargar no, sólo un fragmento de HTML

Comment: Oh, eso esta perfecto asi, entonces ese no es el problema, es que si tenias dos body por ej uno sobreescribe al otro.

Comment: Eso es lo extraño, no tengo error 404 a la hora de cargar el archivo o cualquier otro error, la consulta a la BD lo que trae es la ruta del archivo ,y el archivo sólo contiene una estructura HTML para una tabla, sin header, body, o códigos PHP, JavaScript o JQuery. Entonces por qué me muestra toda la estructura HTML que ya está cargada con el archivo recién llamado?

Comment: Hmmm... creo que hace falta un poco mas de informacion, podrias mostrar por ejemplo una parte pequeña de uno de tus modulos que intentas cargar?, principalmente la cabecera. Lo otro es, debes tener cuidado de que depronto por medio de algun script estes ocultando el componente, ya que puede facilmente estar pasando y tu no darte cuenta, es decir, quizas hayas olvidado esa parte del codigo, quien sabe, habria que mirar muchas cosas.